# text under the image goes at the top of the other images?

Tags: html, css, image, tabs

So I am making this little game, where you need drag text under the images.
I need to make little tabs under the images where the text is needed to be dragged onto.

I thought of placing a div around the image, and another div in the div for the tab, in css I styled the tab to be 25px in height. but the 25px, isn't going under the image in the same div, it's above the other images in that row..

this is what I see, http://prntscr.com/9yv7m8
the red space is the tab, that needs to go under the pictures..

How can I fix this properly?

This is my code,
CSS

```css
body, html {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: georgia, "Comic Sans MS";
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

header {
  height: 5%;
  border-bottom: thick solid grey;
}

footer {
    height: 5%;
    border-top: thick solid grey;
}
.points {
    float: right;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
}

.plaatje {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.plaatje2 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
.igen {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.sprint {
  float: right;

}
.copyright {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 65px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.img {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  float: left;
}
.img2 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  float: left;
}
.answer {
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Words</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <script>
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<header>
 <span class="fa fa-refresh" style="font-size:25px;"></span><span class="igen">&nbsp;igen</span>
 <span class="points"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="font-size:24px"></i>Rigtige:  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 0 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down" style="font-size:24px"></i>Forkerte: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 0</span>
</header>

<div class="container">
<div>
    <img class="img" src="img/cat.jpg" alt="cat" />
    <div class="answer">

    </div>
</div>

    <img class="img" src="img/beak.jpg" alt="beak" />
    <img class="img" src="img/spoon.jpg" alt="spoon" />
    <img class="img" src="img/milk.jpg" alt="milk" />

    <img class="img2" src="img/egg.jpg" alt="egg" />
    <img class="img2" src="img/thee.jpg" alt="tea" />
    <img class="img2" src="img/meel.jpg" alt="meel" />
    <img class="img2" src="img/passport.jpg" alt="passport" />
</div>

<footer>
<img class="dansk" id="dansk" src="img/dansk2.jpg" alt="dansk" />
<img class="sprint" id="sprint" src="img/sprint2.png" alt="sprint" />
<center><span class="copyright"> &copy;2013 laerdansk / FC-Sprint&sup2; Leerbedrijf bronnen </span></center>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try using clear :both

Comment: clear :both does fix part of the problem, i needed the tab beneath the cat picture, and the other pictures still beside the cat.. now the other pictures are still beneath the tab..
I've tried setting all the pictures in divs with tabs beneath it.. but it doesn't solve the problem..
http://prntscr.com/9yv9el
(the red line is the place where the tab is..

and if I try more this happens, 
http://prntscr.com/9yvac1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is this you looking for...

```
<html>
<title>test</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
    .top{background-color: #900; width: 100%; height: 100px;}
    .middle{background-color: #090; width: 100%; height: 600px; float: left;}
    .sidebar{background-color: #ccc; width: 10%; height: 600px; float: left;}
    .container{background-color: #000; width: 90%; height: 600px; float: left;}
    .row{background-color: #fff; width: 100%; height: 100px; float: left;}
    .footer{background-color: #090; width: 100%; height: 100px; float: left;}
    .slice{background-color: #069; width: 33%; height: 100px; float: left;}
    </style>
    <div class="top">top</div>
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="slice">1</div>
                <div class="slice">2</div>
                <div class="slice">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="slice">1</div>
                <div class="slice">2</div>
                <div class="slice">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="slice">1</div>
                <div class="slice">2</div>
                <div class="slice">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        footer
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is not exactly what I'm looking for, altough i can use some of the code quite well, Thanks for the efford!

I need to rebuild this SWF file, into HTML/JS
http://prntscr.com/9yw96v

That is the look I sorta need..